# download profile pictures powershell way

Tags: powershell, user-profile, picture

I am using following powershell (that I got from here http://spsatheesh.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/download-all-the-profile-pictures-through-powershell-using-web-service/)so I can download all the profile pictures. The script runs and displays index number and the profile id (with domain) on the screen. however, profile pictures are not saved.

= = = script = = =

```
[system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO")
[system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")


$SUrl       = 'https://yourcompany.com/_vti_bin/userprofileservice.asmx?wsdl'
$filename   = 'report.csv'



function Download()
{
    trap [Exception]
       {
        Write-Output "-------------------------------Error"     
         Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
         Write-Output "-------------------------------Error"
         continue
       }

        $datel = Get-Date
        Write-Output "INFO: `t $datel `t Job Started"

        Write-Host "Set Path to Store Pictures"  
        $FilePath = Read-Host

        if($FilePath.EndsWith("\") -eq $false)
        {
          $FilePath = $FilePath + "\"
        }

        Write-Host "Enter the User Profile Web Service Url"
        $SUrl = Read-Host

        Write-Host "Enter the User name & Password using which it needs to connect the service"
        #Create Credential Object
        $Credential = Get-Credential

        #Get Service
        #$Service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $SUrl -NameSpace UserProfileService -UseDefaultCredential
        $Service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $SUrl -NameSpace UserProfileService -Credential $Credential


        #Create WebRequest
        $WebRequest = new-object System.Net.WebClient
        #$WebRequest.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
        #$WebRequest.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("palnisam","password","domain")
        $WebRequest.Credentials =  $Credential.GetNetworkCredential()


        #[IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory((Convert-Path (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem)))
        #$Reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($filename)

        $ProfileCount = $Service.GetUserProfileCount()
        $ProfileLoop  = 0;
        $NextIndex = 358;
        for($ProfileLoop = 0;$ProfileLoop -le $ProfileCount;$ProfileLoop++)
        {
            trap [Exception]
            {
            }

            $UPD = $Service.GetUserProfileByIndex($NextIndex)
            $AccountName = $UPD.UserProfile[1].Values[0].Value
            $PictureURL = $UPD.UserProfile[20].Values[0].Value
            if($PictureURL -ne $null)
            {
              $FileName = $FilePath +$AccountName.SubString($AccountName.LastIndexOf("\")+1) + $PictureUrl.SubString($PictureUrl.LastIndexOf("."))
              $WebRequest.DownloadFile($PictureUrl,$FileName)
            }

            $NextIndex = $UPD.NextValue
            Write-Host "$ProfileLoop ----- $AccountName"
        }

}
```

Comment: This is really a powershell question not a SharePoint question, but are you certain that $PictureURL is even being populated?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the User Profile Web Service rather than the SharePoint API? When I run your code I don't get values in PictureUrl, I suspect it is because you are hardcoding the index at 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I got your code working for me. You should change the property getter to look like the following, I left in the original lines for reference:

```
#$AccountName = $UPD.UserProfile[1].Values[0].Value 
$Prop = $UPD.UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "AccountName" } 
$AccountName = $Prop.Values[0].Value

#$PictureURL = $UPD.UserProfile[20].Values[0].Value 
$Prop = $UPD.UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "PictureURL" } 
$PictureURL = $Prop.Values[0].Value
```

I am sure there is a better way in PowerShell, but this should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can download UserProfie pictures from SharePoint 2010 on-premise environment using CSOM code

```
using Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;

namespace ExportUserPictureCSOM
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("InputXml.xml");
string siteUrl = string.Empty;
string password = string.Empty;
string exportImageLocation = string.Empty;
string inputCSVLocation = string.Empty;
string logfileName = string.Empty;
string loginName=string.Empty;         
XmlNodeList root = doc.SelectNodes("Element/InputDetails");
if (root == null)
{
Console.WriteLine("Error Reading Input File");
return;
}

foreach (XmlNode input in root)
{
siteUrl = input["siteUrl"].InnerText;
exportImageLocation = input["ExportImageLocation"].InnerText;
inputCSVLocation = input["InputCSVFullPath"].InnerText;
loginName = input["loginName"].InnerText;

}

if (siteUrl == string.Empty || exportImageLocation == string.Empty || inputCSVLocation == string.Empty || loginName == string.Empty || password == string.Empty)
{
Console.WriteLine("Missing Mandatory Input parameter");
return;
}


ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo credentials = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo(loginName, password);
//  clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
clientContext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = credentials;
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web site = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(site);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", site.Title);
var reader = new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(inputCSVLocation));
int count = 0;
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
var line = reader.ReadLine();
count++;
if (count > 1) //Start from Second Line
{

string email = getEmailID(line);

string userID = line.Split(',')[0].Replace("\"", "");
string firstName = line.Split(',')[1].Replace("\"", "");
string surName = line.Split(',')[2].Replace("\"", "");
email = "i:0#.f|infocentre|" + email;
try
{

var user = site.EnsureUser(email);

string pictureUrl = null;
clientContext.Load(user);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

string newfileName = firstName + "_" +  surName + "_" + userID + ".jpg";
newfileName = Regex.Replace(newfileName, @"[#/?:,*""><~]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
newfileName = exportImageLocation + @"\" + newfileName;

string fileUrl = getImageUrl(email, clientContext, site);

if (fileUrl != null)
{

    Uri destFileName = new Uri(fileUrl);
    string server = destFileName.AbsoluteUri.Replace(destFileName.AbsolutePath, "");
    string serverrelative = destFileName.AbsolutePath;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileInformation f = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, serverrelative);


    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newfileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        f.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
else
{

    Console.WriteLine("User Image not found:" + email);

}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine("Error getting User Details :" + email);

}
}
}



Console.ReadKey(true);
Console.WriteLine();
}

private static string getImageUrl(string userAccount, ClientContext clientContext, Web site)
{


var user = site.EnsureUser(userAccount);

string pictureUrl = null;
clientContext.Load(user);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


int userId = user.Id;
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();

query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
"<Value Type='Integer'>" + userId + "</Value>" +
"</Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Picture'/>" +
"</ViewFields></View>";

ListItemCollection items = clientContext.Web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItems(query);

clientContext.Load(items);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem item in items)
{
FieldUrlValue picture = (FieldUrlValue)item["Picture"];
if (picture != null)
{
//Console.WriteLine(picture.Url);
pictureUrl = picture.Url;
}
}


return pictureUrl;
}

private static string getEmailID(string line)
{
string[] userValues = line.Split(',');
string email = string.Empty;

foreach (var item in userValues)
{
if (item.Contains('@'))
{
email = item.Replace("\"", "");
break;
}
}
return email;
}
}
}
```

**Two input files:**

1. CSV file contains list of users and Email ids(csvInput.csv)
2. Xml input file contains input parameters(InputXml.xml)

**CSV File format:**

```
User ID,First Name,Surname,E-mail,
1233,veera,induvasi,veera@abc.com,
1333,mahesh,gupta,mg@abc.com,
2345,abc,azx,abc@abc.com,
```

More detail: http://veerainduvasi.blogspot.co.uk/2016/10/download-sharepoint-userprofile-picture.html